# Is the distributed lock timeout value in oracle modifiable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, distributed-transactions

In this link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams063.htm)

it says Modifiable:No but range of values is 1 to unlimited. So if it is not modifiable, what does it mean to have a range?

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/676958?start=0&tstart=0 Might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section `modifiable` indicates whether the value of a parameter can be changed **dynamically**(take effect immediately) for a current session(for a duration of a session) using `alter session` statement or for all sessions, using `alter system` statement . If parameter is not modifiable its value can be changed in the server parameter file only (`scope=spfile` option only) and take effect after an instance is restarted.